# Duda, paquetería import glob python

Tags: python, dataframe

Buen día

En este momento estoy realizando un código para extraer información de una carpeta que contiene archivos excel de una encuesta que se realizó. En dichos archivos hay una base con el mismo nombre en todos los exceles y es la información que busco extraer y guardar en un solo dataframe.

Para eso, utilice el siguiente código

```
todos = []


for f in glob.glob('*.xlsm'):
    df=pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Concentrado_encuesta_1')
    todos.append(pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Concentrado_encuesta_1'))


df = pd.concat(todos,ignore_index='True')
```

Donde
Concentrado_encuesta_1: Es la base que voy a extraer de cada uno de los 298 exceles que tengo en una carpeta

Al principio me funcionó bien y pude extraer la información para hacer cálculos. Pero ahora ya me marca un error.
El error consiste en que el primer archivo del que se busca extraer información tiene por nombre "Folio 0018" pero en la variable "f", que es la iteradora, me guarda dicho documento como "~$Folio 0018.xlsm" por lo que el error que me arroja es:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\$Folio 0018.xlsm'

Por lo que entiendo que está buscando el documento con la virgulilla(~) y el signo de pesos y por lo tanto no lo encuentra

Por lo que les agradecería mucho si me pudieran apoyar en saber por qué está agregando estos dos elementos

Saludos

Comment: Esos archivos `~$...` son archivos ocultos que crea Excel cuando has editado el archivo. Se podría validar el nombre del archivo para que no comience por esos caracteres en la expresión que itera en `f`

Comment: para validar que no comience con esos signos puedes hacer `if f.startswith("~$"): continue`